Warning in Higher Order Construct Variable for Cronbach Alpha
After I did the check.keys=TRUE, none of my cronbach values changed. All of it passed the 0.70 threshold.
Why did none of my values change even after application? Would this still be a problem?

Sorry for a probably obvious question, but did you check the keying of your items manually prior to running Cronbach's alpha? Do you have any reverse-coded items?
